# Issue with add watermark on video

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to add an image on a video. Everything works fine except one thing, the image is distorted:

[image]

Here is the code :

```
//Capture the image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.captureView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
self.captureView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let watermarkVideo = WatermakVideo()

//video file
let videoFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoTrim", ofType: "mp4")
let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoFile!)

let imageFrame = captureView.frame
watermarkVideo.createWatermark(image, frame: imageFrame, video: videoURL)
```

Here is the class `WatermakVideo` :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d6i7ap9qu4klp5/WatermakVideo.zip

I would be grateful if you could help me fix this issue.

Comment: How have you designed your captureview? Is there an image inside that view?

Comment: @PuneetSharma There some texts, images, i capture that UIView as an Image and the. Add to video

Comment: Do you know if the distortion comes from the image capture or the video composition?

Comment: Do you build this on real device or simulator?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391651/calayer-contents-not-rendering-correctly-in-avmutablecomposition
It's seams to work only on real device

Comment: @Alban Yes That's true ! it only works on real device

Comment: @Mc.Lover is that the solution of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the below into your file. I had the same issue and solved the problem two weeks ago:

```
-(void)forStackOverflow:(NSURL*)url{
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    //If you need audio as well add the Asset Track for audio here

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];



    CGSize sizeOfVideo=compositionVideoTrack.naturalSize;

    CGFloat scaleWidth = sizeOfVideo.height/self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = sizeOfVideo.width/self.view.frame.size.height;

    // add image
    UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE PATH"];
    CALayer *layerCa = [CALayer layer];
    layerCa.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
    layerCa.frame = CGRectMake(5*scaleWidth, 0, self.birdSize.width*scaleWidth, self.birdSize.height*scaleWidth);
    layerCa.opacity = 1.0;

    // add Text on image
    CATextLayer *textOfvideo=[[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    textOfvideo.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft;
    [textOfvideo setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:64.00])];//fontUsed is the name of font
    [textOfvideo setFrame:CGRectMake(layerCa.frame.size.width/6, layerCa.frame.size.height/8*7-layerCa.frame.size.height/3, layerCa.frame.size.width/1.5, layerCa.frame.size.height/3)];
    [textOfvideo setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [textOfvideo setForegroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];

    UILabel*label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setText:self.questionString];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:64.00]];
    //[label.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [label.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textOfvideo.frame.size.width, textOfvideo.frame.size.height)];
    [textOfvideo addSublayer:label.layer];


    [layerCa addSublayer:textOfvideo];



    CALayer *parentLayer=[CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    videoLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.height,sizeOfVideo.width);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    //[parentLayer addSublayer:optionalLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:layerCa];

    [parentLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];



    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition=[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;
    videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComposition.animationTool=[AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    //AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

    UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    [layerInstruction setTransform:videoTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];


    CGSize naturalSize;
    naturalSize = videoTrack.naturalSize;


    float renderWidth, renderHeight;
    renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
    renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
    videoComposition.renderSize = naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoTrack.naturalSize.height, videoTrack.naturalSize.width);


    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/utput_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exportSession.videoComposition=videoComposition;

    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status)
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Export OK");
                if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath)) {
                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
                }
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportSession.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
                break;
        }
        self.currentUrl = exportSession.outputURL;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });


    }];
}
```

Comment: What is `self.birdSize` ? UIImage ?

Comment: It is my Image Size ,@property (assign) CGSize birdSize. Because i use this Image in two Case . First , when i capture video , this image lay over my UIView. And second , when i glue this Image with Video. But UIView have different size with HD Video for example

Comment: you've got to deal with it?